# Unable to see changes to a global variable from a different Python module

Tags: python, global-variables, python-module

Consider the following Python application of two files, namely `app.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import other


MY_DICT = {'initial': 10}


def main():
    print('before main:', MY_DICT)
    MY_DICT['foo'] = 20
    MY_DICT['bar'] = 30
    print('after changes:', MY_DICT)
    other.check_dict()
    print('back in main:', MY_DICT)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and `other.py`:

```py
def check_dict():
    from app import MY_DICT
    print('inside other:', MY_DICT)
```

I would like to make `MY_DICT` from `app.py` visible in `other.py`. It is visible, but I cannot change it. Here is the output if I run `./app.py` with Python 3.8.0:

```
before main: {'initial': 10}
after changes: {'initial': 10, 'foo': 20, 'bar': 30}
inside other: {'initial': 10}
back in main: {'initial': 10, 'foo': 20, 'bar': 30}
```

Not only `MY_DICT` is back to its initial state when inspected from `other.py`, it's back to the changed state when I return to `main.py`. What is happening here and how do I make it the a real global variable?

I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828738/python-global-variable-between-modules) and ensured that I do re-import `MY_DICT` in `check_dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: don't do that. Do not import the entry point Python script as a module. Create a separate small file which is never imported by anyone else and is intended to be run from the shell.

When you run the app as `./app.py` Python actually loads your `app.py` as a module named `__main__`. But your `other.py` says `import app`, so it imports a separate module named `app`, which is only coincidentally loaded from the same source file `app.py`.

Now you have two instances of `app.py` loaded in your program, each one having a separate `MY_DICT`. Your `__main__` module sees its own `sys.modules['__main__'].MY_DICT`, but `other` module accesses `sys.modules['a'].MY_DICT`. You can check this by printing `id(MY_DICT)` in both `main()` and `check_dict()`: they are different. See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181559/importing-modules-main-vs-import-as-module).

Technically, you can `import __main__ as app` in `other.py`. However, that will break the moment someone tries to use `other.py` in any other way which does not involve starting `./app.py`.